# How to draw a lot of clickable rectangles in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, memory-management, drawing

I'm working on a basic mindmap program but I don't have a lot of experience with drawing with WPF. I want to be able to draw rectangles with text on them and i would like to be able to click on the rectangles to change the text for example. 
As of now I have:

```
private void DrawSubject(int curve, double X, double Y, Brush clr)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.Width = 62;
            rect.Height = 38;
            rect.Fill = clr;
            rect.Stroke = line;
            rect.RadiusX = rect.RadiusY = curve;
            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, X);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect, Y);
            mindmap.Children.Add(rect);
        }

SolidColorBrush line = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 21, 26, 53));
```

minmap is the name of the canvas. I want to be able to draw a lot of these rectangles which present branches of the mindmap. However, when I drew 10,000 of these on random locations the process memory in the diagnostic tools went up by 100 MB, after it was done drawing all of them. I did this to sort of simulate a mindmap with 10,000 branches. So i was wondering if there might be a way to decrease the used memory for these rectangles? 
Or is it better to use DrawingVisual and a grid.click event which checks if the clicked position matches the position of a rectangle by putting the coordinates of the rectangle in a List?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to draw _all_ the elements.  You can implement your own form of virtualization and only render the elements that currently intersect the viewport.  If you store your elements in a quadtree, you should be able to quickly figure out which elements need to be drawn when the layout is updated.  As Dan suggests, it's probably best to use the Drawing APIs, as they are far more lightweight than framework elements, which individually participate in layout and input hit testing.  Better to do the hit testing yourself, in a custom container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would attempt the DrawingVisual method you described, if that proves costly in performance(I don't know how well DrawingVisual works) you could look into embedding [OpenGL](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpgl) or [DirectX](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPFDXInterop) into your application and rendering them via that.

But raytracing drawn visuals rather than making a Control for each is definitely the way to go for your scale.